# Compare 2 listboxes and show nonmatching values in 3rd listbox

Tags: ms-access-2003

I've been working on this for 2 days. Basically I have 2 ListBoxes and I want a command button to compare the values and show the non-matching values (those that appear in the first listbox but not in the 2nd) and list them in the 3rd listbox. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it but here's my code. It errors on the line with the message:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

My listboxes are named CompList1, CompList2 and CompList3.

```
Dim BoolAdd As Boolean, I As Long, j As Long
'Set initial Flag
BoolAdd = True
'If CompList2 is empty then abort operation
If CompList2.ListCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "Nothing to compare"
Exit Sub
'If CompList1 is empty then copy entire CompList2 to CompList3
ElseIf CompList1.ListCount = 0 Then
For I = 0 To CompList2.ListCount
CompList3.AddItem CompList2.Value
Next I
Else
For I = CompList2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
For j = 0 To CompList1.ListCount
If CompList2.ListCount(I) = CompList1.ListCount(j) Then
'If match found then abort
BoolAdd = False
Exit For
End If
DoEvents
Next j
'If not found then add to CompList3
If BoolAdd = True Then CompList3.AddItem CompList2.Value
DoEvents
Next I
End If
```

Comment: CompList1 and CompList2 are populated with field names of tables. The table names will always be the same but the fields will change with each use. Row source types are set to Field List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes:

```
Dim tdf1 As TableDef
Dim tdf2 As TableDef
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb

Set tdf1 = db.TableDefs(Me.CompList1.RowSource)
For Each fld In tdf1.Fields
    sFields = sFields & ";" & fld.Name
Next

sFields = sFields & ";"

Set tdf2 = db.TableDefs(Me.CompList2.RowSource)
For Each fld In tdf2.Fields
    sf = ";" & fld.Name & ";"
    sFields = Replace(sFields, sf, ";")
Next

Me.CompList3.RowSource = Mid(sFields,2)
```

Edit:

[image: Field List, combo properties]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is this meant to be the command button event? When I try to run it between Private Sub CmdComparisonResults_Click() and End Sub I get the error message "Compile error: Expected End Sub"

Comment: I think I could have explained this more clearly. I only want the field names that are in CompList1 but not in CompList2. I'm not concerned with the actual field values.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. When I run the code it errors on the line Set tdf1 = db.TableDefs(Me.CompList1.RowSource) With the error message "Run-time error '3265' Item not found in this collection"

Comment: You are using fields lists, so Me.CompList1.RowSource should be the name of a table. Is this not the case?

Comment: When I look at the Row Source for CompList1 and CompList2, each lists all the fields in the table, not the name of the table. Is there a setting in the properties I should chnge to correct this?

Comment: You are using a fairly recent version of MS Access, yesno? You have set rowsource type to Field List and rowsource to the name of the table that you want to get the list of fields form yesno?

Comment: Wonderful...I got the code working once I set the 1st two list box' Row Source to the table names, and the 3rd list box Row Source Type to Value List. Thank you so much!